# Decoding ASN.1 messages using Openssl asn1parse tool

Tags: rhel, openssl

I am using `openssl asn1parse` tool over `RHEL`, I have my own ASN.1 abstract syntax file, called `TestModule.asn1`, when I am trying to parse a message using following command:

```
openssl asn1parse -inform DER -genconf TestModule.asn1 -in CDRMessage -out test.txt
```

I got the following error:

```
Error on line 1 of config file 'TestModule.asn1'
140411047393096:error:0E079065:configuration file routines:DEF_LOAD_BIO:missing equal sign:conf_def.c:362:line 1
```

Noting that I checked the config file, and it should be free of errors.

Update:

Here is a listing for the first 10 lines in the TestModule.asn1 file:

```
--      File : TestModule.asn1
--

CDRMSG_GA_1040 {iso(1) member-body(2) bsi(826) disc(0) vndr(1249)
Domain (0) charge (5) cDRMSG (1) asn1Module (0)}

DEFINITIONS IMPLICIT TAGS ::=

BEGIN
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should list `TestModule.asn1` in your question, or at least an extract around line 1? It would help considerably :-)

Comment: Added to the question's body.

Comment: I don't think that file is formatted correctly - here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850283/how-to-generate-rsa-keys-using-specific-input-numbers-in-openssl) over on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That openssl command doesn't support ASN.1 schemas.

Looking at the [openssl asn1parse man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/asn1parse.html) the `-genconf` expects a file in a openssl specific serialization format:

> -genstr string, -genconf file
>
> generate encoded data based on string, file or both using `ASN1_generate_nconf` format. If file only is present then the string is obtained from the default section using the name asn1. The encoded data is passed through the ASN1 parser and printed out as though it came from a file, the contents can thus be examined and written to a file using the out option.

Also, `-genconf` isn't supposed to be used in combination with `-in`, cf. the man page examples:

> ```
> openssl asn1parse -in file.pem
> ```

and:

> ```
> openssl asn1parse -genconf asn1.cnf -noout -out asn1.der
> ```

Perhaps some of the confusion comes from different uses of terminology. In strict terms, ASN.1 is a schema language. An ASN.1 structure is thus a part of a schema. A schema specifies how valid documents are structured. With ASN.1 different document encodings are supported - i.e. the so called encoding rules (e.g. BER -> basic encoding rules, DER -> Distinguished Encoding Rules).

There are some people who don't make these distinctions. For example, they also call encoded files ASN.1 files. Or refer to an DER tag as an ASN.1 structure. Take for example the asn1parse man page:

> The asn1parse command is a diagnostic utility that can parse ASN.1 structures

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, do you have any idea that help in decoding an ASN.1 message ?

Comment: @Eng7, you can use the `unber` command from the asn1c package.